# Does GGTracker's APM include camera hotkey usage?

Tags: starcraft-2

I use GGTracker.com to analyse my Starcraft 2 games/replays since it gives me a nice overview of my [SQ](http://www.ggtracker.com/spending_skill) and [APM](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Actions_per_Minute) over time.

I use The Core for my key mappings, and as a Zerg player, I make quite a lot of use of the camera hotkeys - for injecting. It seems to me, however, that GGTracker does not factor in to account the action of repositioning the screen in the APM calculation.

Has anyone else noticed this? Does anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: apm is a useless measurement epm is much better

Comment: @ratchetfreak To be honest, neither is really usefull. You could have a 400+ EPM or APM for that matter, and still performe badly. But I do agree that EPM would be better than APM none the less.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of GGTracker.  You are correct.  Our APM includes all actions except camera movement.

Comment: You're [David Joerg](https://twitter.com/dsjoerg)...

Answer (score 0):

Same goes for Sc2gears. In general, camera hotkeys are not included to the general apm.

https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/version-history/sc2gears122